# TFS 2017/18 Test Hub running a test run with custom drop folder

Tags: automated-tests

I am currently trying to find a way to start a test run from the UI or command line following this [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=vsts). With the command line tool TCM (TFS 2017 and earlier) you could start a test run and provide an alternate build drop location through the switch "\BuildDir", if not provided it would look in the builds drop location stored in TFS.

I am looking for a way to do this in the new way of testing using Test Hub.
I have done a lot of searching but to no avail.

Any help would be very much welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **[Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/test/runs/create)** to achieve the requirement:

```
POST https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/test/runs?api-version=5.0-preview.2
```

For the request body there is

`buildDropLocation` Drop location of the build used for test run.